# Techniques to exceed the maximum texture resolution in Papervision3D?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, bitmapdata, papervision3d

I have an object in Papervision3d that the user needs to be able to zoom into a considerable amount.  At Flash's maximum bitmap size of 2880x2880 the texture is too blurred at the maximum zoom.  Even going beyond this to the sizes available in Flash 10 do not help.

Is there any way to build a BitmapMaterial that can pull from a set of tiled 2880x2880 images?

Is there any other way to load a larger texture into Papervision3D?

Comment: Pretty sure 2880x2880 is no longer the limitation in newer versions of flash player. Anyway, pretty sure the google map API will do what you are looking for. I never used it myself but remember reading it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As The_asMan mention, Flash Player 10 introduced an [larger bitmap size](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/496/cpsid_49662.html) (16,777,215 pixels), and the Google API suggestion is good.

If it helps, another hacky suggestion is to have a separate DisplayObject to be scaled for the zoomed view (either MovieClip or a Bitmap) which can be drawn into a separate BitmapData object using the [draw()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#draw%28%29) method with a **clipRect** argument specified.
The idea is, even though you need a larger resolution image, with the right mapping, you should get a decent result.